# Re-position a video embedded in Wordpress page

Tags: css, wordpress, video

I am trying to re-position a video that is embedded within a Wordpress page. I am trying to get the video to slightly overlap a slider that is at the top of the page. The end result would look something like this: http://www.munsonboats.com/.

Here is a rough draft of MY page with slider at top, and a video that I can't get to budge: http://harddrivemarine.com/DRAFT/?page_id=395.

Here is the div tag I have around the embedded video: `<div id="video-wrap"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/140874518?byline=0" width="440" height="260" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" data-mce-fragment="1"></iframe></div>.`

What CSS is needed so that I can re-position this video so it is at the right and overlaps the slider by approximately half an inch?

Hope this makes sense! Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the css Hope that will help.

```css
#video-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  top: -170px;
  z-index: 999;
  right: 0;
}
h1{
  font-size:28px;
}
```

After putting that css your page will look like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I added your CSS into our "custom css" area, but our page remains the same - the video doesn't budge. I can't see what's preventing it from responding to the CSS? 
http://harddrivemarine.com/DRAFT/?page_id=395

Comment: I mistakenly clicked the arrows to the left of your reply, not realizing it was a rating system. I clicked the down arrow - - please know I was NOT meaning to cast any sort of vote and if I did, it would be a big PLUS. Thank you!

Comment: No prob I just saw your page and I noticed custom css is not loading please add css and clear cache.

Comment: I cleared cache as you suggested, re-saved the CSS, but as you can see, this video refuses to budge! http://harddrivemarine.com/DRAFT/?page_id=395

Comment: I just figured out why its not working BC #logo is not closing in the custom css. Have a look that screen shot http://prntscr.com/crila6

Comment: You are a GENUIS!!!  Thank you, Thank you, so very much!  Voila: http://harddrivemarine.com/DRAFT/?page_id=395